# Mongodb count vs findone

Tags: mongodb

My problem is: There is a collection of users. Im trying to find, does user with `_id=xxx` has `somevalue > 5`.

I'm wondering, what will be faster, using `find(...).count() > 0` or `findOne(...) != null`? Or maybe there is some other, faster/better way?

Comment: Have you tested? `explain` does exist for this reason.

Comment: I still would not know is there a better solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the query times should be almost negligible, because they both limit the bounds of the unique _id, so they will be found immediately. The only slight edge here goes to the `count` because the db will return a int instead of an entire document. So the time you save is purely because of the transfer of the data from db to client.

That being said, if your goal is to do an *exists* query and you don't care about the data, use the `count`

Answer (score 1):

Using count() does not pin the document, in contrary to find(), to the cache, which saves you memory. Memory is your most valuable resource, when using mongodb or any other DB... besides a fast disk.

Comment: Well, except that this thread is 6 months old, what you said seems really legit. Thanks :)

Comment: Sry for replying on an old thread. In my test, *count()* does plant documents onto memory. I could verify this as my first count() query takes >500ms, perform the same query again results in <100ms.