# Mongodb check existence count vs findOne performance

Tags: mongodb, database-performance

I am trying to find out if a document exists or not on my database, and I am kind of curious, what is the best way to do this?
Using

`User.findOne(query).select('_id')`

or

`User.count(query)`

On one hand, findOne returns a 24 hexadecimal string, while count will return only an integer; on the other hand, `.count` it will loop through the whole collection, while `.findOne` will stop at the first matching document.

The only answer I found related to this was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232630/mongodb-count-vs-findone) question, couldn't find anything else, which answer was in favor for `.count`, Mongo has done much work on performance, the question was 6 years ago.

What is more valuable? Memory (findOne) or processing power (count)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some situations where `count` can give you inaccurate results. Also, the performance would be slower than the `findOne()`.

> On a sharded cluster, db.collection.count() can result in an
>   inaccurate count if orphaned documents exist or if a chunk migration
>   is in progress.
>
> After an unclean shutdown of a mongod using the Wired Tiger storage
>   engine, count statistics reported by count() may be inaccurate.

As you are really looking to check the existence of the document, I think `findOne()` is the better option.

Comment: Just want to refer to this post: https://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/
It's telling the opposite, although they don't use count().

Comment: On a sharded cluster, db.collection.count() **without a query predicate** can result in an inaccurate count if orphaned documents exist or if a chunk migration is in progress. - [db.collection.count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#sharded-clusters)

Comment: @val the blogpost claims `find.limit(1)` is faster than `findOne`. This answer claims that's 'arguably benchmarking useless code' https://stackoverflow.com/a/33156959/6305204 Does anyone have reproducible benchmark examples?